# How can I transfer my Bitcoin Android wallet to another platform?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-wallet-app

I have the wallet backup and I was able to decrypt it using these instructions: https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/blob/master/wallet/README.recover

When I went to do the withdrawal the system hung and I now recieve an error telling me the wallet is empty (CouldNotAdjustDownwards did not occur first try). I don't see any record of the transaction on any block explorer.

Is there some other way I use my decrypted wallet? Can anyone suggest a desktop wallet that would likely support this?

I tried replacing wallet.dat in Bitcoin core with no luck.

Comment: Specifically, which was the last line of [README.recover](https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/blob/6aa17a0eebc0bcf5893d098a7e4cc58db1f31bd2/wallet/README.recover) that you ran successfully? And which is the first line where you ran into problems? Also, if you reached [this point in README.recover](https://github.com/bitcoin-wallet/bitcoin-wallet/blob/6aa17a0eebc0bcf5893d098a7e4cc58db1f31bd2/wallet/README.recover#L78-L83), did you discover that you have a PROTOBUF WALLET FORMAT or a BASE58 KEY FORMAT?

Comment: ./wallet-tool dump... says the wallet does not exist, so wallet-tool sync would be the last successful. wallet-tool send was where it hung. It is protobuf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your wallet was created with Bitcoin Wallet for Android 4.0 or later, you can extract the mnemonic (seed) [with this](https://github.com/gurnec/decrypt_bitcoinj_seed), and then restore that seed into a wallet which supports a BIP-39 mnemonic with a BIP-32 path to gain access to the same funds, such as [MultiBit HD](https://multibit.org/) or [breadwallet](https://breadwallet.com/).